# Is there a \subseteqless command?

Tags: relation-symbols

Is there a \subseteqless command? I mean something like \gtreqqless. If not, how can I define it myself.

Comment: Can you post a scan of a hand-drawn approximation of what the composite symbol is supposed to look like?

Comment: Almost :) `\subseteqq` (`amsmath` package)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does one of the following solutions work for you?

[image]

Note that the solutions are only meant to "work" in textstyle and displaystyle math settings. I sincerely hope they will never, ever be used in first-level, let alone second-level, subscript and superscript positions.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\newcommand{\subseteqqsupset}{%
   \mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{$\overset{\textstyle\subseteqq}{\supset}$}}}}
\newcommand{\smallsubseteqqsupset}{%
   \mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{$\overset{\subseteqq}{\scriptstyle\supset}$}}}}

\begin{document}
$u \subseteqqsupset v \smallsubseteqqsupset w$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Stack the symbols, with some small adjustments due to different bounding boxes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\subeqsupset}{%
   \mathrel{\vcenter{
     \offinterlineskip
     \hbox{$\subset$}
     \kern.2ex
     \hbox{$=$}
     \kern-.1ex
     \hbox{$\supset$}
   }}%
}

\begin{document}

$X \subeqsupset Y$

\end{document}
```

[image]